# Is it possible for lower CUDA toolkit version with higher driver version?

Tags: cuda

The hardware seems to newer than the highest-support hardware of the driver version of the lower toolkit. Is it possible for this newer hardware with the newer driver, but with the lower cuda toolkit?

For example, 
the hardware is `NVIDIA GTS 450`, 
the cuda toolkit is `cuda 2.3`, because the driver of `cuda 2.3` seems not to support the `GTS 450`, so I want to install a newer driver, but the toolkit is still `cuda 2.3`.
Does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, older CUDA toolkits should be compatible with newer GPU drivers.  CUDA toolkit 2.3 is very old however, so I don't know what other issues you may run into.  I would suggest updating to a newer CUDA toolkit as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying! A convolution neural network program wrote by Alex is dependent on the old hardware. And the program is wroten for `compute capability 1.3`, when I have tested it on several NVIDIA cards with compute capability `2.1, 3.5 and 5.0`, some errors occurred about `cublasFree` function. The `cublasFree` returns a cublasStatus of 14. So I'm not sure if I should change the version of the driver or toolkit. But the related driver about `cuda 2.3` is not supported for `GTS 450` or `GTX 750 ti`. So I post this question. Could you give some more advice, please? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! The problem is finally solved by `-ccbin`.